# Use the word "Angus" as an adjective based on the meaning of the name?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, idioms, expressions

Based on the Oxford dictionary ***Angus*** is either a type of beef or an area in Scotland while based on wikipedia it also means `one` and `choice`.

I have read in a book of baby names that the name "Angus" means superior and God-like. Is there any solid definition of this word? Does it have the meaning of being powerful as an an informal expression in English literature?

Comment: Godlike? Only to a Scot, surely! Can you tell us where you've heard thst _Angus_ has the meaning _superior_ or _god-like_? OED has none such, but thst's not necessarily definitive.

Comment: @P.E.Dant How about if I want to use this meaning in a professional article (not in literature field)?

Comment: @P.E.Dant Surely Oxford doesnt have this meaning. I guess I have seen it in a non-English dictionary.

Comment: First you must tell us where you've heard that it means "refers to the meaning of being superior and God-like"! It may take that meaning somewhere besides Glasgow, but I've never heard it. I'm happy to be surprised, though! I certainly would not use it in that connexion in a professional article. I would be suspicious of any English word's definition from a non-English dictionary.

Comment: @P.E.Dant How about [this](http://www.sheknows.com/baby-names/name/angus)? Or probably [this](http://www.thinkbabynames.com/meaning/1/Angus).

Comment: Baby name listings are _not_ dictionaries. Those are the meanings of the _name_ "Angus". You could not then say: _"The Arsenal team this year is Angus"._ "Angus" is not an adjective. In the phrase "Angus Beef", it is an attributive or adjunct noun. We don't use proper names as modifers except in that way.

Comment: @P.E.Dant What if I say `Angus_attitude`? or `Angus_method`?

Comment: Of course not, any more than you could say _"a Susan method"_ or _"a very Robert car."_ You will not find useful adjectives in a baby name collection.

Comment: @P.E.Dant but those names are meaningless I guess or at least does not have a trail in ancient methodology.

Comment: On the contrary; "Susan" means "Graceful lily" in Hebrew, and in the original Germanic, "Robert" means "Famed, bright; shining." All names have a meaning, including "Angus". If you use "Angus" in the way you propose, no-one but you will know what you mean.

Comment: @P.E.Dant - This is a fair question that deserves a thoughtful answer. You've pretty much answered the question through civil discourse, but how about turning the corner and summarizing in a succinct answer?

Answer (score 1):

Strange question. "A book for baby names" is absolutely 100% irrelevant to the meaning of "Angus". Take 3 of those kinds of books and they'll give you 3 different meanings. 
The dictionary definition and the "baby name definition" have absolutely nothing to do with one another.

So long story short: No, you can not use the meaning of the name "Angus" in literature by definition of what is said in a "baby name book". As said before, if you do this, no one in existence will understand what you mean, it's basically the same as making up nonexistent words.